# Oracle SQL Sum over partition when grouping by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

| OP | VT | VK | GP | BE | AU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OP1 | VT1 | VK1 | GP1 | 1 | 8 |
| OP2 | VT1 | VK1 | GP1 | 2 |  |
| OP3 | VT2 | VK1 | GP1 | 3 | 8 |
| OP4 | VT2 | VK1 | GP1 | 4 |  |
| OP5 | VT3 | VK2 | GP1 | 5 | 8 |
| OP6 | VT3 | VK2 | GP1 | 6 |  |
| OP7 | VT4 | VK2 | GP1 | 7 | 8 |
| OP8 | VT4 | VK2 | GP1 | 8 |  |
| OP9 | VT5 | VK3 | GP2 | 9 | 8 |
| OP10 | VT5 | VK3 | GP2 | 10 |  |
| OP11 | VT6 | VK3 | GP2 | 11 | 8 |
| OP12 | VT6 | VK3 | GP2 | 12 |  |
| OP13 | VT7 | VK4 | GP2 | 13 | 8 |
| OP14 | VT7 | VK4 | GP2 | 14 |  |
| OP15 | VT8 | VK4 | GP2 | 15 | 8 |
| OP16 | VT8 | VK4 | GP2 | 16 |  |

And I would like to obtaing the below output

| VT | VK | GP | VT_AU | VT_AU8 | VK_AU | VK_AU8 | GP_AU | GP_AU8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VT1 | VK1 | GP1 | 3 | 1 | 10 | 4 | 36 | 16 |
| VT2 | VK1 | GP1 | 7 | 3 | 10 | 4 | 36 | 16 |
| VT3 | VK2 | GP1 | 11 | 5 | 26 | 12 | 36 | 16 |
| VT4 | VK2 | GP1 | 15 | 7 | 26 | 12 | 36 | 16 |
| VT5 | VK3 | GP2 | 19 | 9 | 42 | 20 | 100 | 48 |
| VT6 | VK3 | GP2 | 23 | 11 | 42 | 20 | 100 | 48 |
| VT7 | VK4 | GP2 | 27 | 13 | 58 | 28 | 100 | 48 |
| VT8 | VK4 | GP2 | 31 | 15 | 58 | 28 | 100 | 48 |

S far, I've tried this, but the over partitions cannot go with a group by.

```
-- Logic to obtain the output:
--VT_AU -> grouping by VT, sum of BE
--VT_AU8 -> grouping by VT, sum of BE when AU=8
--VK_AU -> grouping by VK, sum of BE
--VK_AU8 -> grouping by VK, sum of BE when AU=8
--GP_AU -> grouping by GP, sum of BE
--GP_AU8 -> grouping by GP, sum of BE when AU=8

with
  aux (op,vt, vk, gp, be, au) as (
    select 'OP1', 'VT1', 'VK1', 'GP1' , 1, 8 from dual union all
    select 'OP2', 'VT1', 'VK1', 'GP1', 2, null from dual union all
    select 'OP3', 'VT2', 'VK1' , 'GP1', 3, 8 from dual union all
    select 'OP4', 'VT2', 'VK1', 'GP1' , 4, null from dual union all
    select 'OP5', 'VT3', 'VK2' , 'GP1', 5, 8 from dual union all
    select 'OP6', 'VT3', 'VK2', 'GP1', 6, null from dual union all
    select 'OP7', 'VT4', 'VK2', 'GP1' , 7, 8 from dual union all
    select 'OP8', 'VT4', 'VK2', 'GP1', 8, null from dual union all
    select 'OP9', 'VT5', 'VK3' , 'GP2', 9, 8 from dual union all
    select 'OP10', 'VT5', 'VK3', 'GP2' , 10, null from dual union all
    select 'OP11', 'VT6', 'VK3' , 'GP2', 11, 8 from dual union all
    select 'OP12', 'VT6', 'VK3', 'GP2', 12, null from dual union all
    select 'OP13', 'VT7', 'VK4', 'GP2' , 13, 8 from dual union all
    select 'OP14', 'VT7', 'VK4', 'GP2', 14, null from dual union all
    select 'OP15', 'VT8', 'VK4' , 'GP2', 15, 8 from dual union all
    select 'OP16', 'VT8', 'VK4', 'GP2' , 16, null from dual
  )

SELECT
    vt,
    vk,
    gp,
    SUM(be) vt_au,
    sum(case when au=8 then be end) vt_au8,
    sum(be) over(partition by vk) vk_au,
    sum(case when au=8 then be end) over(partition by vk) vt_au8,
    sum(be) over(partition by gp) gp_au,
    sum(case when au=8 then be end) over(partition by gp) gp_au8
FROM
    aux
GROUP BY
    vt,
    vk,
    gp
ORDER BY
    vt,
    vk,
    gp;
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for the columns.  Don't make people guess.

Comment: Apologies, Please find my question edited above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want conditional aggregation with window functions:

```
select VT, VK, GP,
       sum(be),
       sum(sum(case when au = 8 then be end)) over (partition by vt),
       sum(sum(be)) over (partition by vk),
       sum(sum(case when au = 8 then be end)) over (partition by vk),
       sum(sum(be)) over (partition by gp),
       sum(sum(case when au = 8 then be end)) over (partition by gp)
from aux
group by vt, vk, gp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=385f17770e9d62e69aa93f1cfbed8713) is a db<>fiddle.